# How to recover Texture Offset of a chart (Format Plot Area > Picture or Texture fill > Offset)?

Tags: python, excel, vba, com, pywin32

I am using pywin32 (Python) to automate recovery of Excel charts data properties with a Python script. My developments are using the Chart Object Model and VBA a lot since I need to use COM interface.

With Excel file open, you can find a property like that> Format Plot Area > Picture or Texture fill, then there is Offset left, Offset right, Offset top, Offset bottom with some percentages values.

I have the Chart Object. How do I recover this "offset"?

For example, I can recover the Transparency value of the Texture fill with:

```
PlotArea.Format.Fill.Transparency
```

TextureOffsetX and TextureOffsetY do not give any result.

I tried to record a macro to see which properties are changed but the macro is empty after changing an offset.

I also read object documentation: PlotArea, ChartArea, etc.

Answer (score 0):

FYI the best way to find properties like these is to create an object in VBA of the type you're interested in and put a Watch on that object, so you can explore its properties in the watches window.

```
with activesheet.chartobjects(1).chart
    debug.print .chartarea.format.fill.textureoffsetX
    debug.print .chartarea.format.fill.textureoffsetY
end with
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using a Watch and it does help a bit to find properties I need but it's still close to work with the pywin32 Excel Object. Furthermore, it does not solve the issue as the Format.Fill or Format.PictureFormat properties just do not contain the info I need, the offset left , etc. are still nowhere to be found.
When recording a macro and changing values of offset, the step is not recorded and the macro is empty..

Comment: Sorry I posted my comment before finishing sentence.
Indeed, it's not the property I need and when reading the doc the supposed properties would be under .Format.PictureFormat.CropLeft/CropBottom etc.
And the VBA recorder does not work with changing offset values

Comment: I can't even see how you crop an inserted picture used as a "Fill" property, only one which has been pasted into the chart.   Can you describe how the picture is inserted and then cropped?

Comment: Sure ! sorry I should have added the picture right away: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpANu.png

Comment: Yep after seeing that,  I can't find that property either...

Comment: Thanks for helping out anyway, I had hoped it would be due to my poor knowledge of VBA / COM but it does seem like a tricky issue. Unsure how I am going to work around this.